# Gradients returned by tape.gradient is None in Custom Training Loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, tf.keras

I am trying to implement a weighted Binary Cross entropy loss function
Also, I am using a custom training loop for my training

```
def grads_ds(model_ds, ds_inputs,y_true,cw):
    with tf.GradientTape() as ds_tape:
        #ds_tape.watch(tf.convert_to_tensor(y_true.astype('float')))
        #ds_tape.watch(tf.convert_to_tensor(ds_inputs))

        y_pred = model_ds(ds_inputs)
        #print(y_true,y_pred)

        log_logits = np.append(np.log(y_pred),np.log(1-y_pred),axis=0).T
        org_labs = np.append(y_true,1-y_true,axis=0).T
        loss = K.sum(-1*org_labs*cw*log_logits,axis=1)
        loss_value_ds = K.sum(loss)

    ds_grads = ds_tape.gradient(loss_value_ds,model_ds.trainable_variables)

    return loss_value_ds, ds_grads
```

`y_true` and `y_pred` both is of shape (1,3) and `cw` is of shape (3,2)

`cw` is

```
[[0.5145 3.6036]
 [1.7163 0.7127]
 [2.4231 0.6708]]
```

`ds_tape.gradient` is returning `None` gradient.
I even tried adding `ds_tape.watch` for the input and the true labels `y_true`. But still receiving `None`.

In my network, I used `tf.math.reduce_max` after a certain layer. Can that be the source of the problem?

Or is it becasue of I used numpy functions on tensors `y_pred`?

`tf.GradientTape().gradient()` returns `None` when the target and source are `UNCONNECTED`. I cannot figure out how it is unconnected.

NOTE : When I used `tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true,y_pred)` no error as such mentioned above occured. Only when I used a custom loss calculation code instead of the keras function, this error is occurring

Any solution?
None of the methods I saw on the web works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, by rewriting the code using functions from `tf.keras.backend`

```
def grads_ds(model_ds, ds_inputs,y_true,cw):
    with tf.GradientTape() as ds_tape:
        y_pred = model_ds(ds_inputs)
        logits_1 = -1*y_true*K.log(y_pred)*cw[:,0]
        loss = logits_1 + logits_0
        loss_value_ds = K.sum(loss)
    ds_grads = ds_tape.gradient(loss_value_ds,model_ds.trainable_variables,unconnected_gradients=tf.UnconnectedGradients.NONE)
    return loss_value_ds, ds_grads
```

Moral of the story : `numpy` functions cannot be used on tensors. If used, the computational graph does not remain connected.

Comment: I agree that it is best to use backend functions were possible, but when you say "If used, the computational graph does not remain connected." is that true even when wrapped in TensorFlow functions like [tf.py_function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_function) and [tf.numpy_function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/numpy_function) ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
K = tf.keras.backend
(x_trn,y_trn),(x_val,y_val) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
model = get_simple_1conv_1dense_model(x_trn,y_trn)
g = grads_ds(model, x_tst, y_tst, cw=1) # hopefully cw=1 makes sense
```

Ultimately, your function returned a bunch of `None` gradients:

```
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=nan>, [None, None, None, None])
```

However, it seems fairly straightforward why.  While running, it produced an error:

```
/path/to/anaconda3/bin/ipython:9: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  if __name__ == '__main__':
/path/to/anaconda3/bin/ipython:11: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
  sys.exit(start_ipython())
```

Dividing by zero is most likely your culprit.

With a little more finagling, I found this line to cause the error:

```
log_logits = np.append(np.log(y_pred),np.log(1-y_pred),axis=0).T
```

Comment: `cw` is actually a (3,2) array. I forgot to mention. You can use 1. In that case, it reduces to binary_crossentropy().

Comment: In my code, y_pred is not 0 or 1 for any of my inputs, in the 1st iteration at least. I have updated my question. Please give it a read

Comment: Your updated question is definitely more informative.  Glad you figured it all out.  (Swapping out `np` for `K` should have caught my eye when I copy-and-pasted your function.  Good catch.)